# Generate an image with "in-image-padding" for facebook og:image images

Tags: gatsby, sharp, gatsby-image

We are in the last steps to go productive with a Gatsby **2.32.13** (on Netlify) site:

```
  System:
    OS: macOS 11.5.1
    CPU: (16) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10700K CPU @ 3.80GHz
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.16.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node
    npm: 7.17.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/npm
  Languages:
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 92.0.4515.131
    Firefox: 90.0.2
    Safari: 14.1.2
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^2.32.13 => 2.32.13
    gatsby-background-image: ^1.5.3 => 1.5.3
    gatsby-image: ^3.5.0 => 3.7.1
    gatsby-plugin-feed: ^2.10.0 => 2.13.1
    gatsby-plugin-fontawesome-css: 1.0.0 => 1.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-google-gtag: ^2.9.0-next.0 => 2.9.0-next.0
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^2.9.1 => 2.12.1
    gatsby-plugin-mdx: ^1.7.1 => 1.10.1
    gatsby-plugin-offline: ^3.7.1 => 3.10.2
    gatsby-plugin-preload-fonts: 1.9.1 => 1.9.1
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^3.7.0 => 3.10.0
    gatsby-plugin-root-import: ^2.0.5 => 2.0.6
    gatsby-plugin-sass: ^2.8.0 => 2.8.0
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^2.14.4 => 2.14.4
    gatsby-plugin-sitemap: ^2.12.0 => 2.12.0
    gatsby-plugin-typography: ^2.9.0 => 2.12.0
    gatsby-remark-autolink-headers: ^2.8.0 => 2.11.0
    gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files: ^2.7.0 => 2.10.0
    gatsby-remark-images: ^3.8.1 => 3.11.1
    gatsby-remark-normalize-paths: ^1.1.0 => 1.1.0
    gatsby-remark-prismjs: ^3.10.0 => 3.13.0
    gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe: ^2.8.0 => 2.11.0
    gatsby-remark-smartypants: ^2.7.0 => 2.10.0
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^2.8.1 => 2.11.1
    gatsby-transformer-json: ^2.8.0 => 2.11.0
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^2.9.0 => 2.12.1
    gatsby-transformer-yaml: ^2.8.0 => 2.11.0
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby-cli: 3.11.0
```

**Edit: shorter version of my question? Possibly, Sharps `extend` is a solution. (How) Does [gatsby-plugin-sharp](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-sharp/#gatsby-plugin-sharp) support [Sharps extend](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-resize#extend) parameter?**

We have some hundred brand images (logotypes) and we should use them for `og:image` images. These are the recommended dimensions: `1200 pixels x 627 pixels`. Successfully, we generate the images like this:

```
childImageSharp {
  fixed(quality: 100, width: 1200, height: 627, fit: CONTAIN) {
    ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
  }
}
```

But they are ugly due to missing paddings. So, we should produce a `1200x627` white empty image and center a smaller logotype image inside. The smaller logotype is no problem. For example:

```
childImageSharp {
  fixed(quality: 100, width: 600, height: 313, fit: CONTAIN) {
    ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
  }
}
```

But how to transform this smaller image **with equal padding around** to an `1200x627` image?

Is this possible with Gatsbys sharp support?

If it helps. Our development version is online https://sx.surface-world.de/ and shows some logotypes.

Thanks for spending your time!